# JavaScript Plugin, Node is Object, should be HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript

I have got the below (Simplified for this issue) plugin, the `node` value which is the value of `options.container` it an HTMLObject however when I do typeof on it `Object` is returned.

This is an issue as when i try to override this using dataset values, I detect it's type and replace it accordingly.

```
// Define option defaults
  constructor(node) {
    const _ = this;

    var options = {
      container: node,
    };

    (function() {
      for( const data in node.dataset ) {
        var key = (data.replace("map", "")).charAt(0).toLowerCase() + (data.replace("map", "")).substr(1), 
            value = node.dataset[data];

        // Check the value has been set
        if (value !== '') {
          switch(typeof options[key]) {
            case 'object':
              options[key] = JSON.parse(value);
            break;
            case 'HTMLElement':
              options[key] = value.GetElement();
            break;
            default:
              options[key] = value;
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      console.log(options);
    }.call(_));


    // Initialize the map
    // this.init();
  };

  static init(node) {
    return new this(node);
  }
  static initAll(node) {
    var _ = this,
      instances = [];

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      var maps = document.querySelectorAll('[data-map]');
      var current = [];
      var InitializeMap = function (e) {
        instances.push(_.init(e)); // Setup new instance of this class for each map
      };

      // Keep a reference for each map
      for (var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
        var dataset = maps[i].dataset;
        if (current.indexOf(dataset.googleMap) === -1) {
          current.push(dataset.googleMap);
          InitializeMap(maps[i]);
        }
      }
    });

    return instances;
  }
```

As you can see in the code below, I get an attribute called `data.map.container`, which contains the value of `#map_container`. So during that `switch` function I need to detect that the `node` value is an `HTMLObject` not an `object`.

For the record is I do `console.log(options.container)` then the HTMLElement is displayed in the log.

P.S. `GetElement()` simply takes the string and returns the HTMLObject, so `#element` would do getElementById and `.element` would do getElementByClassName. Just my version of jQuery's $().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typeof` can not tell such specific object types, see possible return values: https://developer.mozilla.org/hu/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

You can use `instanceof` to check for whatever class you need.